# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jsUpload.js:97 xhr.onload

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome

Sorry for re-posting this, but after searching the internet for several days and looking through stackoverflow and many other sites I am still no closer to solving this issue. I am a huge noob when it come to JavaScript and I just seem to be constantly stuck on this.

There seems to be an issue with the following code. I keep getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < xhr.onload

```
 function getFile(fileId){
    log('Checking whether to resume upload');
    var fileData = localStorage[fileId];
    if (fileData){
        var  fileParts = fileData.split("|");
        log ('Resuming upload from package '+(parseInt(fileParts[2])+1));
        setDetails({
            fileId:fileParts[0],
            token:fileParts[1],
            currentPackage:fileParts[2]
        });
    }else{
        log ('No upload to resume, informing server to initialize a new upload');
        // submit file information to server
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('totalSize', self.totalSize);
        formData.append('type', self.type);
        formData.append('fileName', self.fileName);
            //error lies from here on
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', self.url, true);
        xhr.onload = function(e) {

            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (response.action=="new_upload"){
                log ('New upload initialized with ID '+response.fileid+' and token '+response.token);
                setDetails(setFile(fileId,response.fileid,response.token));
            }
        };
```

I just can't for the life of me figure out where I have gone wrong with this. any help pointing me in the appropriate direction would be brilliant. So far I have tried deleting all the < characters and still no luck. I even went on Jsonlint.com to try and validate but still no such luck.

```
//managed to track the error dow to this through JSONlint:
    {
    responseText="<br><table border='1' c.../div></td></tr></table>",
    mozResponseArrayBuffer=ArrayBuffer,
    more...
    }

//with the error output as:
    Parse error on line 1:
    {    responseText="<br><t
    -----^
    Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Where have I gone wrong with this?

Comment: If you edit an old post it will come at the 'interesting' page again, with the time of the last edit. No need to repost!

Comment: Is this just a typo in your post: `JSON.parse('xhr.responseText');`? `xhr.responseText` should be unquoted here.

Comment: ooo thats my fault, thats a typo on my behalf.

Comment: I don't think it's in your code itself - it's the XHR response that has an invalid character when you're trying to parse it as JSON. try to use `try...catch` in cases like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it due to it trying to parse an entire web page. fixed now after using Mozilla Firebug to track down my error even further.